# Simple graphic problem

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, paint

I have never really had to worry about how "pretty" my programs are before but I'm working on something for marketing now.... Anyways I imagine this is pretty simple but I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. Basically I have a panel with a bunch of picture boxes in it and I am drawing colored rectangles behind them to create a pseudo "frame" around the photos. It has a different frame based on whether or not the photo is selected. The default selected photo is in position 0 and on the first time it paints everything looks great. But when the selection is changed, the paint event fires and nothing changes. Here's the code:

```
private void panelPicSet_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.Clear(panelPicSet.BackColor);
    foreach (PictureBox picBox in panelPicSet.Controls)
    {
        if (picBox == selectedPhoto.PictureBox)
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(53, 73, 106)), new Rectangle(new Point(picBox.Location.X - 4, picBox.Location.Y - 4), new Size(picBox.Width + 8, picBox.Height + 8)));
        if (picBox == hoveredPicBox)
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(53, 73, 106)), new Rectangle(new Point(picBox.Location.X - 2, picBox.Location.Y - 2), new Size(picBox.Width + 4, picBox.Height + 4)));
        else
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 166)), new Rectangle(new Point(picBox.Location.X - 2, picBox.Location.Y - 2), new Size(picBox.Width + 4, picBox.Height + 4)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining the selectedPhoto variable?

Comment: In a picture box click event. The hovered is set in the mouse enter/mouse leave events. Both are being recognized correctly in the paint event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I suspected it was an easy answer. I had to call `panelPicSet.Invalidate()` in the click and mouse enter/ leave events. I had assumed that clearing the graphics object in the paint event was performing the same function but apparently not.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. Sorry I could not follow up sooner, I have been dodging tornados. @Bill - thanks for the vote down - next time I'll make sure to reply in spite of the horrific weather conditions!